# Irreducibility of Cyclotomic Polynomial proof question

Tags: abstract-algebra

The proof begins with:

Let $f(x) = \phi_p(x+1) = \frac {(x+1)^p - 1}{(x+1)-1} = x^{p-1} + \binom{p}{1}x^{p-2} + \binom {p}{2}x^{p-3} + ... + \binom {p}{1}.$

Where are the binomials coming from?

Comment: From [Newton's binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). Notice that $x+1-1=x$ in the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the binomial expansion, we have that
$$\frac {(x+1)^p - 1}{(x+1)-1}=\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}x^k-1\right)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^p\binom{p}{k}x^k=\sum_{k=1}^p\binom{p}{k}x^{k-1}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^p\binom{p}{p-k}x^{k-1}=\binom {p}{p-1}+\dots  + \binom{p}{1}x^{p-2} +x^{p-1}.$$